# Invalid Index trying to call a simple Oracle PROCEDURE from Java

Tags: java, spring, ojdbc

The following SQL block successfully displays "Y" or "N" when called based upon whether or not the procedure is running against production database or not.

```
DECLARE
  v_is_prod VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN

  FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION2(v_is_prod);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_is_prod=' || v_is_prod);
END;
```

I am trying to call this procedure from Java (this is my first ever call). For this question, please disregard that this should probably be a function that returns a char and not a single-output varchar2(1) parameter. I'm taking baby steps.

This is my Java code:

```
public String isRunningInProduction() throws DaoException {
        
        LoggerUtil.info("Start calling [" + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + "]::", LOGGER);
        String inProduction = "";
        
        try {

            SqlOutParameter isProd = new SqlOutParameter("v_is_prod", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

            List<SqlParameter> paramList = new ArrayList<SqlParameter>();
            paramList.add(isProd); 
            
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {

                public OracleCallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                    OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) connection
                            .prepareCall(IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION);
                                        
                    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                    return callableStatement;
                }
            }, paramList);

            inProduction = (String)resultMap.get("v_is_prod");
                                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while determining if running in prod or not, PROC_NAME::[" + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + "]," + e);
            throw new DaoException("Error while retreiving " + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + e);
        }
        LoggerUtil.info("Finished calling [" + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + "]::", LOGGER);
        
        return inProduction;    
        
    }
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: CallableStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Apparantly, registerOutParameter is 1-based, so that callableStatement doesn't appear to be the issue, the first parameter has an index of 1.

The following const is defined elsewhere:

```
public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2";
```

Any suggestions on what my issue may be?

Comment: Try getting rid of paramList.

Comment: @OldProgrammer ty for the reply. paramList is a required parameter for the jdbc template.call, but, to try to follow your suggestion, I did not add the isprod sSqlParameter to the paramList and I commented out the registerOutParameter statement. I got the error: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. Did u have something else in mind than what I tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to indicate in your statement that an argument is required, like this:

```java
public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?);";
```

Usually the statement is wrapped in a `call` invocation:

```java
public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "{call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?)}";
```

Please, note the inclusion of the parenthesis and the `?` character.

In Java and JDBC, you need to provide a placeholder, using the `?` character, for every parameter required in your SQL statement, no matter whether if it is IN or OUT.

As you don't provide such placeholder in your example, Spring is complaining because you are trying to register an out parameter with index `1`- you are right, the first column index is `1` -, but there is no placeholder for that parameter in your SQL statement.

Please, for further examples, consider for instance review [this article](https://lalitjc.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/different-ways-of-calling-stored-procedure-using-spring/), it could be of help.

Comment: I made the change and now got this error: Error while retreiving FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?)org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I think the problem is that a semicolon is missing at the end of the statement, it is necessary in Oracle: `public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?);";` - note the end `;` in the statement. Please, see the updated answer. Please, could you try again?

Comment: Bingo! I actually had to remove the semi colon following the (?) to get it to work, but you basically had it. Please update your answer and I will happily select your response as the Answer. it's been a pleasure doing business with you! This was the line used: public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "{call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?)}";

Comment: That is great. I am very happy to see that the answer was helpful and please, sorry for the error: there is a long time without using JDBC; thank you very much for pointing out my mistake. Please, don't hesitate to contact me again if you need further help

Comment: if you are interested, I posted anotehr similar question on how to change the Java code if I changed the package procedure to be a function instead of a procedure with a single output parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71757342/how-to-write-java-that-calls-a-package-function-making-a-slight-change-to-worki

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Of course Chad, I am glad to help: I posted a possible solution to your new question. I hope it helps.