# How to write Java that calls a package function? Making a slight change to working Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-framework-beans

With the help provided in the response to my previous question:

[Invalid Index trying to call a simple Oracle PROCEDURE from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668896/invalid-index-trying-to-call-a-simple-oracle-procedure-from-java)

I was able to call an Oracle package procedure that returns  a single varchar2(1) output parameter but now I would like to change the procedure to a FUNCTION with the following SPEC that returns a CHAR:

```
FUNCTION is_running_in_production RETURN CHAR;
```

How do I modify the code below that called the earlier version of the procedure that returned a single output parameter to instead calll this procedure which calls a FUNCTION that returns a CHAR field?

```
public static final String IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION = "{call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2(?)}";

public String isRunningInProduction() throws DaoException {
        
        String inProduction = "";
        
        try {

            SqlOutParameter isProd = new SqlOutParameter("v_is_prod", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

            List<SqlParameter> paramList = new ArrayList<SqlParameter>();
            paramList.add(isProd); 
            
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {

                public OracleCallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                    OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) connection
                            .prepareCall(IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION);
                                        
                    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                    return callableStatement;
                }
            }, paramList);

            inProduction = (String)resultMap.get("v_is_prod");
                                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while determining if running in prod or not, PROC_NAME::[" + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + "]," + e);

        }
                
        return inProduction;    
        
    }
```

Since but the jdbcTemplate.call procedure seems to require a paramList, I commented out the adding isProd to paramList and passed a paramList with zero parameters added. I also changed callableStatement.registerOutParameter to callableStatement.registerReturnParameter and changed the data type from Types.VARCHAR to Types.CHAR. Iif any of this is right, I'm not sure how I would extract the result to populate the return variable inProduction.

```
public String isRunningInProduction() throws DaoException {
        
        String inProduction = "";
        
        try {

            //SqlOutParameter isProd = new SqlOutParameter("v_is_prod", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);                       
            List<SqlParameter> paramList = new ArrayList<SqlParameter>();
            //paramList.add(isProd);            
            
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {

                public OracleCallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                    OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) connection
                            .prepareCall(IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION);
                                        
                    
                    //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                    callableStatement.registerReturnParameter(1, Types.CHAR);

                    return callableStatement;
                }
            }, paramList);

            inProduction = (String)resultMap.get("v_is_prod");  
            
                                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while determining if running in prod or not, PROC_NAME::[" + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + "]," + e);
            throw new DaoException("Error while retreiving " + IS_RUNNING_IN_PRODUCTION + e);
        }
        
        return inProduction;    
        
    }
```

I get the following error on the initialization of the resultMap object, before I even have to deal with getting the result.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
```

Comment: For starters, you're still registering the param as `Types.VARCHAR` and you're casting the result as `String` (which is incompatible with a java `Character` object).

Comment: Hi @Chad. Sorry for the late response, I just realized your update. Thank you very much mate, I really appreciate it. It wasn't necessary, I'm glad to help, and I don't expect anything in return. Thank you very much again. Please feel free to contact me again if you need.

Comment: Hi @Chad. I am sorry to ask, but if you wanna to actually reward an existing answer, due to the fact that it was posted before the bounty was defined, the only way is to  explicitly award it; on the contrary the bounty will be lost. As I told, it doesn't matter, but I found it a very frustrating situation every time it happened to me before.

Comment: Hi @Chad. Honestly mate, I have no words... Thank you very much, it was completely unnecessary... The previous bounty was lost because, as explained in the `How is a bounty awarded?` section in the [bounty help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), a bounty can only be automatically awarded to an answer if, among other things, the answer was posted after the bounty was created. In other words, the only way to award a bounty to an existing answer, an answer posted before the bounty was created, is to manually award it. Again, thank you, thank you very very much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke a function, I would suggest following a similar but different approach of the one you followed in the linked question based on `jdbcTemplate.call`.

For example, you could try using the [`execute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCallback-) method of  `JdbcTemplate` and `CallableStatementCreator`, in a very similar way to in your example, but with more control of the output result:

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

try {
  String result = jdbcTemplate.<String>execute( new CallableStatementCreator() {
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection)
          throws SQLException {
          CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2}");
          // The first out parameter is the result of the function
          // Set the appropriate type
          cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
          // Set the rest of the arguments, if required
          return cs;
        }
      },
    new CallableStatementCallback<String>() {
      public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)  throws SQLException {
        cs.execute();
        String result = cs.getString(1);
        // The value eturned here is the one returned by the execute method
        return result;
      }
    }
  );

  System.out.printf("Result with CSC: '%s'", result);

} catch (Throwable t) {
  // Please, forgive me for this
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or, simplified with lambda expressions:

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

try {
  String result = jdbcTemplate.<String>execute(connection -> {
    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2}");
    // The first out parameter is the result of the function
    // Set the appropriate type
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    // Set the rest of the arguments, if required
    return cs;
  },
    (CallableStatementCallback) cs -> {
      cs.execute();
      String result1 = cs.getString(1);
      // The value returned here is the one returned by the execute method
      return result1;
    }
  );

  System.out.printf("Result with CSC: '%s'", result);

} catch (Throwable t) {
  // Please, forgive me for this
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please, note how the actual SQL expression is contructed:

```
{? = call FDS_APPS.FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2.is_running_in_production2}
```

This code can be greatly simplified using the [`SimpleJdbcCall` class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html). Please, consider the following example:

```java
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

try {
  SimpleJdbcCall isRunningInProductionFunction = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName("FDS_APPS")
    .withCatalogName("FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2")
    .withFunctionName("is_running_in_production2");

  // Indicate the return type. You can pass additional arguments if you need to
  String result = isRunningInProductionFunction.executeFunction(String.class);
  System.out.printf("Result as simple JDBC call: '%s'", result);
} catch (Throwable t) {
  // Please, forgive me for this
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please, consider review the [Spring Data Access documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc): it is plenty of examples and alternative solutions.

Comment: Both examples worked for me with minor changes. For the first example, I modified the generic return type to String to avoid a warning:       new CallableStatementCallback<String>() { public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)  throws SQLException {.... For the second example, I added the schema portion: SimpleJdbcCall isRunningInProductionFunction = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("FDS_APPS").withCatalogName("FDS_USR_SEC_PKG2").withFunctionName("is_running_in_production"); For the benefit of other users, could you upd the answer and I will selct it?

Comment: Hi @chad. I am very happy to see tht both approaches worked properly with minor tweaks. Sorry mate, and thank you very much for the comments, all of them make perfect sense. Please, don't hesitate to contact me again if you need to, I will be glad to help.